# Update specific batch of records from minute to minute on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch-file

Sorry in advance if the question makes little sense.
I need to know how to update a table every X seconds/minutes/hours.

I normally do something like this:
`UPDATE myTable SET someField = someField WHERE id_ofMyTable > 0 and id_ofMyTable < 1000`

After this query, some XMLs files are created thanks to a second Stored Procedure.

The problem is that I want to update all the `id_ofMyTable` from 0 to the max. But if I make an update without the id_ofMyTable parameter then the XMLs get corrupted or the server that "fetch" the XMLs gets overloaded.

Does anybody know a way to update the table every 'x' time instead of me doing a manual UPDATE whenever I see that the XMLs were fetched?

I hope my question make sense and I apologize in advance if it seems totally wrong. I'm more than happy to elaborate more on the topic if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, let us make it simple (only if you do not want to use SQL Agent).

In Sql Server Management Studio Run the following script, please modify it as per your need.

```
DECLARE @DATA_ID INT
DECLARE @MAX_DATA_ID INT

SET @DATA_ID = 0
SELECT @MAX_DATA_ID = MAX(id_ofMyTable) FROM MyTable

WHILE @DATA_ID <= @MAX_DATA_ID
BEGIN    
    IF @MAX_DATA_ID - @DATA_ID >= 1000
    BEGIN
            UPDATE myTable SET someField = someField WHERE id_ofMyTable >= @DATA_ID AND id_ofMyTable < @DATA_ID + 1000
        SET @DATA_ID = @DATA_ID + 1000
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
             UPDATE myTable SET someField = someField WHERE id_ofMyTable >= @DATA_ID AND  id_ofMyTable < @DATA_ID + (@MAX_DATA_ID - @DATA_ID)
        SET @DATA_ID = @DATA_ID + (@MAX_DATA_ID - @DATA_ID)
    END
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01' --Set your sleep time here.    
END
```

You can run it and leave it. One drawback is you need to run it manually, once and then again if there is a disconnection with SQL Server.

Comment: Is there a duplicated END? also should the 0 and the 1000 on the update must be DATA_ID and MAX_DATA_ID respectively?

Comment: Hi, yes it was a typo. I have fixed that. As I said you will need to modify the script. The main focus is WAITFOR DELAY <TIMESPAN>

Answer (score 0):

A SQL Agent job can be scheduled to run SQL batches at defined time intervals.

Information on how to configure and use SQL Agent can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx).

Comment: Thanks! But I'm looking more for a "on-demand" way. Instead of a job.